# Is there a way to do a callback function on all text that matches a regex?

Tags: jquery, regex

I am creating a bookmarklet that pulls prices from a page (like let's say Amazon) using a regex and I would like to be able to pull additional information regarding the fontsize of each price being pulled as a way for ranking their importance.

Below is a code I have generated that isclose to what I am looking for. match() creates an array of prices and :contains goes back through and re-searches each of the found prices for their fontsize. However, this would be a problem if the same price comes up twice.

I am looking for a way to do it all in one step.
Any advice would be appreciated.

```
var prices = jQuery('body').text().match(/[\$€£]\s*(?:\d[\d,]*(?:\.\d+)?)/g);
    jQuery.each(prices, function() {
        var size = parseInt(jQuery(":contains('" + this + "')").css('fontSize'));
    });
```

Comment: Can't you access the prices by the ID of their dom elements?

Comment: @Jivings: Clearly not, if it's a bookmarklet meant to run on random pages.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It looks to me that the price always has the same `class` on Amazon. Why can't that be used?

Comment: @Jivings: My impression was that Amazon was just an *example*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You could be right. Or this could be an XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've to iterate  through the results of the container elements

```
var prices = jQuery('body').text().match(/[\$€£]\s*(?:\d[\d,]*(?:\.\d+)?)/g);
var results = [];
jQuery.each(prices, function() {
    var price = this;
    results[ price ] = [];
    jQuery(":contains('" + this + "')").each( function() {
        var size = parseInt( $( this ).css( 'fontSize' ), 10 );
        results[ price ].push( size );
    } );
});
```

`results` is now an array with the prices as key and all corresponding font-sizes as values of the keys